# Autocomplete not firing on first input

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

so I've googled, searched here, went everywhere, and I can't find an answer. I'm using jQuery UI autocomplete to search a list of item ids numbers. They can be any length from 1 - 99999.

The Issue:

When I type '2' for example, nothing happens, then I hit backspace and type '2' again and this time, anything starting with 2 appears below, and the event shows up in the "Network List" on developer's tools. Furthermore, when I search 1, only 1 shows up, but it's not performing the search it's just spitting back the input value. but when i hit backspace and type in 1 again, the search fires and I get the same results as I did with 2. Normally no matter what number I type it should just fire by default shouldn't it? How do I correct this and get my autocomplete working properly.

CODE:

```
    $('.item-inventory').on('keyup', '#item_num', function(){
        //var search = $(this);
        var itemname;
        var itemprice;
        var itemdesc;
        $(this).autocomplete({
            delay : 100,
            source: function(request, response){
                $.ajax({
                    url: '../assets/server/orders/item_search.php',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: {search: request.term},
                    success: function (data){
                        var keys = data.search;
                    //  $('#item-name').val(data.search[0].item);
                    //  itemPrice = data.search[0].price;
                    //  itemDesc = data.search[0].desc;
                        response($.map( keys, function(i){
                            return{
                                label : i.id
                            };

                        }));

                    }
                });
            },
            minLength : 1
        });
        //$('#item-search-results').removeClass('hidden');
        $(this).on('autocompleteselect', function(event, ui){
            $('#item-search-results').removeClass('hidden');
        });
    });
```

Comment: You are reconnecting `autocomplete` over and over on every `keyup` event. That is not the way to go :( can you provide sample HTML too?

Comment: I've seen no issue when I use this method in another input field.

Comment: That does not mean it is a) correct or b) that changing it is the solution to your problem :)

Comment: I can see the problem staring at me, but without your HTML the answer will be not so useful. I will try anyway.

Comment: throw up your answer because I think i figured it out myself, but I would like to see what you say, then I'll fire back with my solution if it is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are connecting the autocomplete after the first keypress (which is too late for the first keypress). You are also reconnecting it on every keypress.

You need to connect the autocomplete once at startup to any relevant element.

e.g.  place this outside of the key handler:

```
    $('.item-inventory #item_num').autocomplete({
        delay : 100,
        source: function(request, response){
            $.ajax({
                url: '../assets/server/orders/item_search.php',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {search: request.term},
                success: function (data){
                    var keys = data.search;
                //  $('#item-name').val(data.search[0].item);
                //  itemPrice = data.search[0].price;
                //  itemDesc = data.search[0].desc;
                    response($.map( keys, function(i){
                        return{
                            label : i.id
                        };

                    }));

                }
            });
        },
        minLength : 1
    });
```

Comment: that's exactly what I did, I read what your first comment was and put two and two together, give it five minutes and I'll accept

Comment: Thanks again for all your help, once again I learned something new! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can add more event **keydown** like here:

```
$('.item-inventory').on('keyup keydown', '#item_num', function(){
........
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If not works Properly then At Page load call the autocomplete function with empty array of strings.
 E.g. $("input").each(function () { $(this).autocomplete({ src: [] }); }); 
Now this will work at first keypress also. Best of Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please initialize the autocomplete in ready function.
Like : $(Id).autocomplete();